# How can I create a file or a remote file with activex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, activex

I want to create a file .txt with activex and javascript.
I've tried this but it's not working.
Maybe I've install something to use activex. 
I don't know where is my mistake. I've looked for before asking my questions here.

this is html part

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Choix du code CNI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="i2.css">

</head>
<body>

<div style="padding: 50px 0px; text-align: center;">

<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Choix du code CNI</p>
</div>


<select name="codeCNI" id="codeCNI" size=1 ">
            <option selected="selected"> </option>
            <option>VH:  Humanis
            <option>CI:  CreIrcafex
            <option>BT:  CRR
            <option>AG:  AG2R
            <option>IR:  Ircem
            <option>CP:  Crepa
        </select>
        <br/><br/>

<input type='button' id='valider_cni_value' name='pseudo' value='Valider Code CNI' onclick="createNewFile()"/>

    </div>



 <script src="i2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is javascript part

```
var fso, objet;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

   function createNewFile(){


    objet = fso.CreateTextFile("C:/monfichier.txt", true);

    fso=null;

     }
```

Comment: fso is not safe for scripting. besides most of the file system is sandboxed. you need to write your own activex that calls IEGetWriteableFolderPath to get a writable location.

Comment: Ok thanks. It work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the path.

The path is not this : `C:/monfichier.txt`

It's : `../monfichier.txt`